# How can i remove all html tags from get_the_content()?

Tags: php, the-content

i want to remove all html tags from content like `<p>, <br>, <img>, <a>` i `tried strip_tags()`
also tried

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

but not working for me. any reliable solution ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The WordPress function, at least the one I tend to use, would be [`wp_filter_nohtml_kses`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_nohtml_kses). That should remove all of the HTML, but you need to be careful not to put some HTML back by running `the_content` filters on your HTML-less string.

I am not sure why `strip_tags` didn't work, but I suspect that you doing something else in other code posted or not posted and that that something else is undoing your tag stripping, or putting some tags back. Mainly I think that because you tried ...

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

... and apparently expected tags to be stripped?

Comment: Yes! you were right. `strip_tags()` does not work because of `$content = get_the_content();
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);`
Thank you Mate.

Comment: Now both solutions worked for me `wp_filter_nohtml_kses()` and `strip_tags()` :)

Answer (score 14):

To build upon @s_ha_dum's answer I think you want.

```
$content = get_the_content(); 
echo wp_filter_nohtml_kses( $content ); //or strip_tags
```

Comment: Wouldn't you still need the content filter? So something like `wp_filter_nohtml_kses( apply_filters( 'the_content', $content ) )`?

Answer (score 2):

This removes both `<htmltags>` and `<!-- comments -->`:

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() );
```

`wp_filter_nohtml_kses()` didn't get me rid of the comments.

[seen here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106008/how-can-i-display-the-content-in-plaintext)