# How can i display the content in plaintext

Tags: loop, excerpt, the-content

i want to display my excerpt in plaintext. How can i do this?

This is my Snippet where i display the content:

```
<?php the_content(__( 'Weiterlesen &rsaquo;','okay')); ?>
```

How i change the snippet to display the content in plain?

greets,
niklas

Comment: `<?php the_content();?>` should do the trick

Comment: No, '<?php the_content(); ?>' shows the content **with** html-tags, but i won´t html-tags and formats in my text. u know?

Comment: Use `get_the_content` with a filter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `wp_strip_all_tags()` to remove the content of `script` and `style` elements too:

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_content() );
```